# Far Manager: Easy way to zip file to the other panel?

Tags: far-manager

In Far Manager, is there an easy way to copy / move a file to the other panel ?
When I press F5 or F6 to copy / move a file, the file appears in the other panel. Amazingly With `F11` - ArcLite, a zipped copy of the file is reated in the same folder. Can I easily do  it similarly to F5 / F6, with the exception of that  I want a zipped copy of the file to appear in the other panel, as if it were " copy to zip" / "move to zip" to the other panel. That is, for "move to zip" I no longer need this file, but I want its zipped copy  in the other pane. The current way to do it is  `F11` - ArcLite then `F6` Can this be done in a simpler/ more direct way ?

Comment: Have you tried `Shift-F1` (and `Alt-z` afterwards to create a zip instead of gzip)? I don’t have access to Far right now so I am not sure in which panel the archive will be created.

Comment: Why use plugin commands while there is built-in support for archives (`F9`/`Files`). As the above commenter noted, `Shift-F1` will do the job. `F1` or [Far Manager shortcuts](https://iamhow.com/Technical_Notes/Cheatsheets/Far_Manager_shortcuts.html) to the rescue.